# How to detect which segmentcontrol was deselected

Tags: xcode, delegates, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

I know that there isn't a delegate method for UISegementcontrol but I need to fire a delegate method when a segementcontrol button is deselected and need to know which segment was deselected.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When the selected segment is changed, the control will send its action methods. You register a target to receive an action method using:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

When the target receives the action method, the sending segment control will be the `sender` argument. You can learn the newly-selected segment by querying its `selectedSegmentIndex` property.

There's no direct way to learn the segment that used to be selected. You'll have to track that yourself. You would have a property on your controller, say `lastKnownSelectedSegmentIndex`. You would set that initially a view load time, by querying the segment control's `selectedSegmentIndex`. Then, when the selected segment changes, you can consult that property to learn which segment was deselected. You also need to update that property with the new value so that it's correct the next time.

```
- (IBAction) action:(UISegmentedControl)sender
{
    NSInteger deselectedSegmentIndex = self.lastKnownSelectedSegmentIndex;
    self.lastKnownSelectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

    // Now you can make decisions based on deselectedSegmentIndex and/or sender.selectedSegmentIndex ...
}
```